# Delphi - RoundTo - always down

Tags: delphi, rounding

I need to round a floating point number to two decimal places, but always down. Now I use `RoundTo(number, -2)`, but it does the rounding mathematically correctly, which is undesired behavior for my situation. Let the reason, why I need to do this, aside...

I eventually achieved it using this:

```
var a,b: currency;
    floatStr: string;
    format: TFormatSettings;
    localeDec: char;
begin


  format:= TFormatSettings.Create;
  localeDec:= format.DecimalSeparator;
  format.DecimalSeparator:= ',';
  System.SysUtils.FormatSettings:= format;

  a:= 2/30;
  floatStr:= floatToStr(a);
  b:= strToCurr(
      copy(floatStr, 1, ansiPos(',', floatStr) + 2)
  );
  showMessage(currToStr(b));

  format.DecimalSeparator := localeDec;
  System.SysUtils.FormatSettings:= format;

end;
```

However, this solution just doesn't feel right. Is there a "mathematically clean" way to do it, without messing with strings and resetting decimal separators etc. ? I searched a lot, but didn't find any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Multiply the value by 100.
2. Truncate to an integer, towards zero.
3. Divide the value by 100.

Like this:

```
function RoundCurrTo2dpTruncate(const Value: Currency): Currency;
begin
  Result := Trunc(Value*100) / 100;
end;
```

I've assumed that by rounding down you mean towards zero. So 0.678 rounds down to 0.67 and -0.678 to -0.67. However, if you want to round towards -∞ then you should replace `Trunc` with `Floor`.

```
function RoundCurrTo2dpDown(const Value: Currency): Currency;
begin
  Result := Floor(Value*100) / 100;
end;
```

Another way to tackle the problem is to recognise that a `Currency` value is simply a 64 bit integer with an implicit shift of 10000. So the entire operation can be performed using integer operations, unlike the code above which uses floating point operations.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Real_Types):

> Currency is a fixed-point data type that minimizes rounding errors in monetary calculations. It is stored as a scaled 64-bit integer with the 4 least significant digits implicitly representing decimal places. When mixed with other real types in assignments and expressions, Currency values are automatically divided or multiplied by 10000.

For example you could implement `RoundCurrTo2dpTruncate` like this:

```
function RoundCurrTo2dpTruncate(const Value: Currency): Currency;
begin
  PInt64(@Result)^ := (PInt64(@Value)^ div 100)*100;
end;
```

Note that here the arithmetic has been an shifted by 10000. So multiplication by 100 has become division by 100. And so on.

Comment: I believe `Int` is better than `Trunc` because `Trunc` potentially may overflow.

Comment: @user246408 I actually think it's better to do the whole thing using integer operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetRoundMode with old Delphi RoundTo

```
SetRoundMode(rmDown);

function RoundTo(const AValue: Double; const ADigit: TRoundToRange): Double;
var
  LFactor: Double;
begin
  LFactor := IntPower(10, ADigit);
  Result := Round(AValue / LFactor) * LFactor;
end;
```

Obviously it was changed in recent versions

Comment: Yeah, I got that wrong. Still, the question is about `Currency`.

Comment: Yes, that is not suitable. I read just the first part "round a floating point number to two decimal places".

Comment: Fair enough. Asker is a little confused. Currency is fixed point.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it commes from the variety of experiments I did. I have been using various types, but currency is the one I will be using at the end.